# Reading a zip file need to get plain text instead binary stream

Tags: java

I have written binary stream to zip file. When I unzip I see the binary characters. 
Please help me on How to get plain text ?

Read method - issue i need to get plain text i saved instead binary stream

```
 public static void readzipBytes(String filePath){
    try {
          ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(filePath);
          Enumeration entries = zf.entries();


          while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
            ZipEntry ze = (ZipEntry) entries.nextElement();



              long size = ze.getSize();
              if (size > 0) {
                System.out.println("Length is " + size);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(zf.getInputStream(ze)));
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                  System.out.println(line);

                  byte[] bytearray =  line.getBytes("UTF-8");
                  System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+bytearray.length);
                  for(int o=0; o<bytearray.length; o++){
                    System.out.println("SSS=="+bytearray[o]);

                }

                  String str = new String(bytearray);
                }
                br.close();
              }

          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Save method

```
 public static byte[] savezipBytesWithWriter(String filename, String message) throws IOException {
        byte[] input = message.getBytes();
        System.out.println("intput length"+input.length);
        File f = new File("C:\\tmp\\t113.zip");
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream (f); 
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(baos);
        writer.write(message);


        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(filename);
        entry.setSize(input.length);
        zos.putNextEntry(entry);

        System.out.println("baos barray length"+baos.toByteArray().length);           
        zos.write(baos.toByteArray());
        zos.closeEntry();
        zos.close();
        System.out.println(baos.toString());
        baos.writeTo(outputStream);
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
```

Save method

Comment: There is no performance difference in converting byte array as string, It gives you the descent way of storing too, I mean will not get corrupted.

Comment: I need to write binary stream. Zip has to be read only via a program and need to avoid manual reading. Is this possible to get plain text from binary stream ?

Comment: When you write binary stream it is not plain text

Comment: it is the data that you write that is either binary or text.  Where in your code do you think you are `writing` binary?

Comment: zos.write(baos.toByteArray()); this writes binary stream.

Comment: The data is text. Data coverts to binary. as above

Answer (score 1):

```
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);;
```

Here you are constructing a `ZipOutputStream` around a `ByteArrayOutputStream.`

```
Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(baos);
```

Here you are constructing a `Writer` around the same `ByteArrayOutputStream.`

```
writer.write(message);
```

Here you are writing a message directly to the `ByteArrayOutputStream.`

```
zos.write(baos.toByteArray());
```

Here you are writing the content of the byte array of the `ByteArrayOutputStream` that the `ZipOutputStream` is wrapped around, to the `ZipOutputStream.`

Basically this code doesn't make sense.

Try writing the message directly to the `ZipOutputStream.` You don't need the `ByteArrayOutputStream` at all. Just construct a `FileOutputStream,` a `ZipOutputStream` around that, and a `Writer` around that.

Comment: Then how to make the content binary stream?

Comment: Just a minute. Try it my way before you ask more questions.